# Comando Python subprocess.check_output

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

Estou chamando um programa em Java via comando `subprocess.check_output` do Python. Não está dando certo. Neste comando passo um arquivo como parâmetro.

Tem algo de errado no comando abaixo?

```
import subprocess

def chamaProg(arquivo):
    r = subprocess.check_output(["java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SDK_Java_v1.0.0.2_Beta\SDK Java_v1.0.0.2 BETA\Lib" -jar C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Busca3-N_java\dist\Busca3-N_java.jar",arquivo])
    return r
```

Comment: O problema, provavelmente, está nas aspas. Tente usar apóstrofos da seguinte forma: `subprocess.check_output(['java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SDK_Java_v1.0.0.2_Beta\SDK Java_v1.0.0.2 BETA\Lib" -jar C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Busca3-N_java\dist\Busca3-N_java.jar',arquivo])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira certa de invocar `subprocess.check_output()` ou `subprocess.Popen()` é passando cada termo do comando em um elemento da lista/array, e não criando uma string longa. Você também precisa prestar atenção às barras invertidas, elas precisam ser codificadas:

```
r = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-Djava.library.path="C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SDK_Java_v1.0.0.2_Beta\\SDK Java_v1.0.0.2 BETA\\Lib"', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Busca3-N_java\\dist\\Busca3-N_java.jar', arquivo])
```

Menos importante, mas eu também sempre recomendo não escrever o caminho para arquivos ou diretórios explicitamente, pois isso assume que você tem certeza qual o sistema de arquivos sendo utilizado (FAT, NTFS, ext3, HFS). Pode ser que no seu caso você realmente tenha certeza que esse código só será executado em Windows, rodando NTFS. De toda forma, minha sugestão é:

```
import os
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
java_lib = os.path.join(home, 'Documents', 'NetBeansProjects', 'SDK_Java_v1.0.0.2_Beta', 'SDK Java_v1.0.0.2 BETA', 'Lib')
jar_path = os.path.join(home, 'Documents', 'NetBeansProjects', 'Busca3-N_java', 'dist', 'Busca3-N_java.jar')
r = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-Djava.library.path="{}"'.format(java_lib), '-jar', jar_path, arquivo])
```